# Python .join() iterable string

Tags: python, string, iterable

I am trying to find an easy way to add a dot `.` to each 3 digit as a string (`'43434' -> '43.434`) and I found an interesting use of join for this task:

```
num = '1234567'
new_num = '.'.join(num[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3))
# new_num = 123.456.7'
```

Well its close to what I want. This is what I want:

```
(its need to be `'1.234.567'`)
```

Why does it work like that? 
When I use slicing on join, it adds the addition for each item:

```
num = '2333'
>>> '.'.join(num[0:2])
<<< '2.3'
>>> '.'.join(num[0:3])
<<< '2.3.3'
```

I read somewhere that its called string as iterable concept. Can someone help me understand it?

Comment: `num[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3)` - This is a [generator expression](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/). A quick Google search didn't show any good beginner introductions to generators, so I've linked the PEP proposing their introduction to the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your first code sample picks up 3 digits at a time of the number and joins them. Breaking it up

```
>>>num = '1234567'
>>>x=[num[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3)]
>>>x
['123', '456', '7']
>>>'.'.join(x)
'123.456.7'
```

The `num[i:i+3]` part is  called slicing and explained [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

While in the second part you use the [join function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to connect the parts again.

```
>>>num = '2333'
>>>num[0:2]
23 
>>>'.'.join('23')
2.3
```

What you want is `1.234.567`, i.e. you want to start counting three digits from the *end* of the string. One way would be to reverse the string, do what you are  doing and reverse the result.

```
>>> num = '1234567'
>>> num[::-1]
'7654321'
>>> '.'.join(num[::-1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3))[::-1]
'1.234.567'
```

Comment: Wow! I can use the slice twice? i did `'.'.join(num[i:i-3:-1] for i in range(-1, -(len(num))-1, -3))` and then reverse it again.

Comment: `num[::-1]` returns a string which you then slice. so `num[::-1][i:i+3]` is equal to `x=num[::-1]; x[i:i+3]`. Your way essentially does the same, as you take advantage of negative indices in Python.

Comment: i didn't saw the generator there. though that `join` somehow know how to jump between string.

Answer (score 5):

Possible way,

```
>>> num = '1234567'
>>> '.'.join([num[i-3 if i-3 > 0 else 0:i] for i in range(len(num),-1,-3)][::-1])
'1.234.567'
```

A benchmark,

```
$ python -mtimeit -s'num="1234567"' '".".join(num[::-1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3))[::-1]'
100000 loops, best of 3: 4.15 usec per loop

$ python -mtimeit -s'num="1234567"' '".".join([num[i-3 if i-3 > 0 else 0:i] for i in range(len(num), -1, -3)][::-1])'
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.87 usec per loop
```

Neither one stands out as clearer to me but if you prefer the first (popular solution posted) it's only slightly slower.

Comment: How about `max(i-3, 0)` instead of the awkward `if`?  Seems slightly slower than your `if`, though, at least on my machine.

Answer (score 2):

If you try:

```
>>> a = (num[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3))
>>> a
<generator object <genexpr> at 0x028C2B48>
```

So the first one is essentially using:

```
new_num = '.'.join(a) # iterating with generator
```

Alternatively, you can do with `list`:

```
new_num = '.'.join([num[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3)]) 
# iterating with list ['123', '456', '7']
```

This explains your code as well, since you can see `string` as `list`:

```
'.'.join(num[0:3]) # num[0:3] -> '233' string -> ['2', '3', '3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Roughly, what an iterable is is something for which this code will work:

```
for x in some_iterable_here:
    print(x)
```

The idea is that an iterable is a sequence of values. Lists are iterables. If `some_iterable_here` was the list `[1, 23, -7, 'hello']`, the code above would print out the number `1`, `23`, `-7`, and lastly the string `'hello'`.

A string is one kind of iterable -- it's a sequence of characters. So if you put in the string `'hello'` for `some_iterable_here`, it'd print out each letter individually: `'h'`, `'e'`, `'l'`, `'l'`, then finally `'o'`.

What `join` does is take each element in an iterable containing strings (for example, a list of strings like `['one', 'two', 'three']`, or just the string `'four'`, which is an iterable containing the strings `'f'`, `'o'`, `'u'`, and `'r'`) and return a new string that's all the strings put together, with something in between.

So when you get the slice `num[0:3]`, that's the string `'233'`. Python combines each character with a period in between when you do `'.'.join` on it, and that's how you get `'2.3.3'`.

Answer (score 1):

Try This Solution

```
(".".join([num[::-1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3)]))[::-1]
```

Comment: parentheses is extra. It work `".".join([num[::-1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3)])[::-1] -> '1.234.567'`

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you:

```
In [15]: num = '1234567'
#Reverse string with [::-1]
In [16]: new_num = '.'.join(num[::-1][i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(num), 3))
#Repeat reverse for correct result
In [17]: new_num = new_num[::-1]
In [18]: print new_num
1.234.567
```